# How to make text appear in the corner of a ggplot with log scales

Tags: r, ggplot2

I usually use infinite values in the position aesthetics of ggplot text objects to make labels appear in the corner of the plot regardless of the data scale. I mainly use this when making multi-panel figures which should have letters in each panel to identify each panel in the figure legend. However, this does not seem to work with log scales if I want the label to appear on the left or bottom, since obviously transforming log(-Inf) returns NaN. Is there an easy fix for this? I could do a long workaround but I was hoping there is something easier. Example is below:

```
notlogdata <- data.frame(x = 1:3,y = 1:3)
ggplot(notlogdata, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = -Inf, y = Inf, l = 'a'), aes(label = l), hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1)

logdata <- data.frame(x = 10^(1:3), y = 10^(1:3))
ggplot(logdata, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = -Inf, y = Inf, l = 'a'), aes(label = l), hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

First plot with untransformed axes appears fine:
[image: plot with untransformed axes]

The second plot does not have a label and returns the warning:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced
>   2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).

Comment: You have defined `x = -Inf, y = Inf` then used `scale_x_log10`. You cannot take `log` of `inf`.

Comment: See [cowplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html), for putting multiple ggplots together with labels

Comment: You can take a log of `Inf` --- `log(Inf)` is `Inf`. The issue is you can't take a log of a negative like `-Inf`, but `log(0)` is `-Inf`, so if you set `x = 0` it will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a log of `Inf` --- `log(Inf)` is `Inf`. The issue is you can't take a log of a negative like `-Inf`. But `log(0)` is `-Inf`, so if you set `x = 0` it will work as expected.

```
ggplot(logdata, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(
    data = data.frame(x = 0, y = Inf, l = 'a'),
    aes(label = l), hjust = -0.5, vjust = 1
  ) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
annotation_custom(gTree(children=gList(textGrob("a", hjust=0,x=0,vjust=1,y=1))))
```

[image]

Comment: What if we have multiple facets, and we want a different label on each facet?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible to use negative positioning aesthetics, including `-Inf`, on a log-transformed axis. Here is a solution using cowplot as suggested by zx8754

```
library(cowplot)

notlogdata <- data.frame(x = 1:3,y = 1:3)
notlogplot <- ggplot(notlogdata, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point() 

logdata <- data.frame(x = 10^(1:3), y = 10^(1:3))
logplot <- ggplot(logdata, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()

plot_grid(notlogplot, logplot, labels=c('a','b'), hjust=-8)
```

This outputs the plot below:

[image: cowplot image]